# How to exclude ORDER BY filter with Scrapy to prevent crawl too many pages?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, data-science

How to prevent [scrapy](/questions/tagged/scrapy) crawler same items with different filter order like:

[image]

to use only the default order

Comment: can't you remove this part from url manually before you send `Requests` ?

Comment: or you can try to write own [middleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html) which will do the same.

Comment: I use `CrawlSpider` to do this, I was trying to do with rules, not worked, maybe with a middleware can thanks, @furas.

Comment: in documentation I found also class [dupefilter](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class) which filter duplicate request. Maybe in internet or on Stackoverflow you can find something more about this filter.